# How to clean transparent silicone/jelly cases?

Tags: cleaning, phone

I have here my jelly case on my smartphone. After 2 months, i saw that it getting yellowish and i don't know how to clean it. 
But every month, I clean it with cloth and alcohol, but nothing's change.

Do you know any way to properly clean it?

Comment: is it possible for you to post a photo of the jelly case, a before(1st use) and after(current yellowed). It will help us understand what caused it. whether it is Color fade? UV effect? or abrasion ? etc

Answer (score 2):

Yellowing of materials that touch your skin can be the result of the oils on your skin being transferred to your phone case. Most likely, if this is the cause the most pronounced discolouration will be where your skin touched the case.

Remedy: Remove the case periodically and wash it with a mild soap, dry, and replace on the phone.

Overall yellowing of the case evenly is probably something in your environment reacting to the composition of the case material. It is probably not something "cleanable." Being able to change this might be unfeasible and/or impractical.

Remedy: Don't you just love yellow silicone phone cases?

Avoid harsh cleaning materials, cleansers, and miracle liquids.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to follow these steps:

1. Take a bowl of water
2. Pour some ['Ujala stiff and shine'](http://www.jyothylaboratories.com/stiff-and-shine.php).
3. If you can not get this product, try for similar color regaining products used for clothes.
4. Immerse your phone cover into this bowl and keep some heavy material onto it so as to ensure that it gets immersed for some while.
5. After some time, remove the weight and take the cover out of the bowl.
6. Apply some of your face washing cream and make a foam on it using your bare hand rub.
7. Wash it under fresh water.

Answer (score -1):

Some phone cases leave marks or small scratches on the phone. If this happens, take the cover off and use a microfiber cloth to rub the phone well. If scratches are still visible, apply some denatured alcohol to the microfiber cloth and rub the phone again.

If your phone is significantly damaged by the case and you have an iPhone and have only ever used the original Apple phone case, consider taking the phone and case into the Apple store. Show them the marks and scratches on your phone and see what they will do for you.

If you have only mild stains or your case is dirty with dust and grime, then all it needs is a good wash. Grab a small bowl and fill it with warm water and dish soap. Use a toothbrush or similar gentle brush to scrub the dirty or mildly stained areas. This solution is great for giving your case a quick clean. It will look good as new.

Another alternative:

Fill a large bowl with warm water. Add about a tablespoon dish soap, or citrus-based cleaner. Place something heavy on your case to keep it submerged and let it sit for a few minutes. Use a soft brush to gently scrub to remove stains or dirt. Repeat as needed and rinse with cold water. Make sure to dry your case well before installing back onto your iPhone.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the specific question about yellowing of silicone jelly phone cases